# Unbounded sequence proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and suppose there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $S$ converging to a number $x_0 \notin S$. Show that there exists an unbounded continuous function on S.

Here's my proof (can someone please verify it?): Consider the function $f:S \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \displaystyle{\frac{1}{x-x_0}}$. This function is defined at all points in $S$, and is continuous. Also, $f$ is unbounded. To see this, consider a sequence $(x_n)$ in $S$ converging to $x_0$. Now, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\exists b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_b - x_0| < \frac{1}{n}$. But then, $|f(x_b)| > n$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me, but given that $n$ is used as the index of the sequence $(x_n)$, I would not write

> "$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_b - x_0| < \frac{1}{n}$."

Instead, I would use a letter other than $n$ in the second instance; let's say $k$. Then you could have

> $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \exists b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_b - x_0| < \frac{1}{k}$.

Furthermore, the link between $x_b$ and $k$ (in my version, or $x_b$ and $n$ in your version) is not (notationally) clear. To rectify this, you could instead say

> $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n_k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_{n_k} - x_0| < \frac{1}{k}$.